# How to resolve CVT1100 in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm working on a medium-sized project which uses qmake to generate Visual Studio 2005 project files. I'm trying to get it built under Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Since qmake doesn't support this IDE yet i had the provided conversion assistant convert my solution.

When trying to build I get the following error in one of the subprojects:

> CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:VERSION,name:1,language:0x0407

After what Google's results told me it seems that this error is likely to occur when migrating to a newer version of Visual Studio but I don't know why and the hacks recommended there don't work for me.

What I already tried is to rename the ressources to random numbers, even a different "name" at every occurence of the version information.
When I build the project again after reading the error and deleting the corresponding .RC-file it works once. But that's too much of a hack.

Any ideas anyone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

I resolved that problem when moving from VC++ 2010 to 2012 by changing the setting under Configuration Properties>Manifest Tool>Input and Output>Embed Manifest to **NO**. I have no idea what that is all about, but I looked at the contents of the `.manifest` file, and it sure looks like I can live without it being embedded.

Comment: I had this issue when project was migrated from older VS

Comment: This answer is wrong, but no point in creating a new answer since this already has upvotes. You are getting a "duplicate" error because VS is generating its own manifest, and then you have ALSO specified your own manifest under `Manifest Tool>Input and Output>Additional Manifest Files`. And `Embed Manifest` to "No" means you don't have a manifest file. The correct solution is leave that as "Yes" to embed your custom additional manifest file, but instead tell VS not to create its own manifest. You'll find that property under `Linker>Manifest File>Generate Manifest` and set that to "No"

Comment: Had a similar issue with migrating a VS6 project to VS2005: `CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:MANIFEST, name:1, language:0x0409`. Setting `Manifest Tool>Input and Output>Embed Manifest` to **NO** fixed it, whereas `Linker > Manifest File > Generate Manifest` setting doesn't change the error.

Comment: Had the `CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:MANIFEST, name:1...` error with the VS2019 toolchain with a project that was converted to CMake. Issue was resolved by adding `target_link_options(my_exe PRIVATE /MANIFEST:NO)`

Answer (score 14):

I recently solved the similar problem with Qt 4.8.2 and Visual Studio 2012. Qt 4.8.2 does not support VS2012 as mkspec, so I copied `win32-msvc2010` mkspec to `win32-msvc2012` (changing `_MSC_VER` to 1700) and used some other workarounds (QtWebKit fix, etc. — you can find them over the internet) to build Qt 4.8.2 with VS2012. But qmake was not aware of VS2012 `.vcxproj` project files, so it continued to generate VS2010 projects. After conversion of these project files to the new 2012 format in the VS the above error arose.

**The solution** was to exclude generated `.res` files from build in all configurations (both Debug and Release). To do this, open 'Generated Files' folder in Solution Explorer, right click the `.res` file, open Properties, select 'All Configurations' from drop-down list and set 'Excluded From Build' property of 'General' section to 'Yes'.

It is quite tedious to repeat these actions by hands every time, so I wrote Python script to automate this. You can use it (at your own risk!) to update qmake-generated `.vcxproj` files.

```
    import sys
    import os
    from xml.etree import ElementTree

    def updateProject(filename):

        def getXmlns(tag):
            return tag[1:].split('}')[0]

        tree = ElementTree.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        xmlns = getXmlns(root.tag)
        for cb in root.iter('{' + xmlns + '}CustomBuild'):
            if(not 'Include' in cb.attrib):
                continue
            if(not cb.attrib['Include'].endswith('.res')):
                continue
            for excl in cb.iter('{' + xmlns + '}ExcludedFromBuild'):
                if('Condition' in excl.attrib):
                    del excl.attrib['Condition'] # delete ExcludedFromBuild condition
        ElementTree.register_namespace('', xmlns)
        tree.write(filename)

    if(len(sys.argv)>=2): # use project files specified in command line:
        for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
            updateProject(sys.argv[i])
    else: # update all project files in current directory:
        for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if(filename.endswith('.vcxproj')):
                updateProject(filename)
```

Thanks to [Xandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169036/xandy) for pointing out that you'll need to pass working directory to `listdir()` for script to work in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you, I just came across a similar situation and that Python script was most useful. I had to modify the call to `listdir()` using `os.getcwd()` as its parameter to make it work in my machine (Python 2.7.3).

Comment: This solution worked for me for Qt 4.8.5 and VS 2013.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever encounter this error while compiling (usually a downloaded project from internet), then remove the manifest file and remove the reference to the manifest file in the .rc file.

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/163759/Solve-CVT1100-duplicate-resource-type-MANIFEST-iss)

Comment: On the other hand, I have no manifest file in project, I tried to disable embed manifest and I still have this error (but I am user of Visual Studio C++ 2010 (no updates on VS or VS Service Packs)).

Comment: +1 for getting me on the right track. For me, I had to remove the *.rcv file which which held duplicate resource definitions. Then I had to remove the references to it in the *.rc file. Everything compiled fine after that without changing any linker settings.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this problem, and by accident ended up with a project file that didn't have the resource conflict.  In my case I was importing a QT qmake generated project for VS2008 into VS2010.  After using VcprojFormatter and a lot of diffs, I found the difference (for me).  I think it is a bug in either the import wizard, or the core of VS 2010.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/vcproj_formatter.aspx

My resource file was called win32_resources.rc  You'll need to edit each intermediate data folder corresponding to your build configurations (release, debug, etc)

Look for a section like the following in your vcxproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="debug\win32_resources.res">
    <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  </Resource>
  <Resource Include="release\win32_resources.res">
    <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  </Resource>
</ItemGroup>
```

All the "Resource" text should be replaced with "CustomBuildStep":

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomBuildStep Include="debug\win32_resources.res">
    <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  </CustomBuildStep>
  <CustomBuildStep Include="release\win32_resources.res">
    <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  </CustomBuildStep>
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem in the VS2008 file is that the default(?) setting was not explicit:

```
<File RelativePath="release\win32_resources.res">
  <FileConfiguration
    Name="Debug|Win32"
    ExcludedFromBuild="true"
    >
    <Tool Name="VCCustomBuildTool"/>
  </FileConfiguration>
</File>
```

The "Tool Name" field was missing.

Answer (score 3):

> If you ever encounter this error while compiling (usually a downloaded
>   project from internet), then remove the manifest file and remove the
>   reference to the manifest file in the .rc file.

**This answer by hB0 was 100% correct for the case I encountered.**

*This was very useful to me and I would like others to benefit from knowing this, rather than assuming hB0's answer should be ignored because others have votes and hB0's has zero votes. I have to say it in a separate answer because I the system will not let an unregistered user vote. I even registered so as to be able to vote on this answer but the system still will not let me vote till I am a more mature user.*

Answer (score 2):

This is a stretch, but I had a similar problem under Visual Studio 2005.  It might help, or be totally off base:

I was linking with a static library (.lib) that has its own version resource - very reasonable, it shows the library's version.  On some stations, my app would link.  On other stations, I'd get the same duplicate resource message you got.

It turned out to be related to a linker optimization setting:  "Use Library Dependency Inputs" (UseLibraryDependencyInputs=), possibly combined with "Link Library Dependencies".  When "Use Library Dependency Inputs" was enabled, the linker was being fed the .obj and .res files that were used to build the .lib, instead of just searching the .lib.

The problem is that you *don't want* the .lib's .res file as an input file to the linker. My project has its own version resource.  If you bring in the .lib's resources, you now have two version resources, hence the error.  If the linker simply searches the .lib, it has no reason to bring in the .lib's resource, and all is well.

My project's configuration didn't force the setting of "Use Library Dependency Inputs", it inherited it.  On some stations, it inherited "No", and I could link.  On some stations, it inherited "Yes", and we got the error.

If Visual Studio 2010 still has this setting, try forcing it off.

Comment: Makes sense, but playing with these settings doesn't change anything about my error.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was seeing in VS2005!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was resolved by ensuring any included .rc files were excluded from the build, except the main .rc that was #including the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was resolved by ensuring any included .rc files were excluded from the build, except the main .rc that was #including the rest.
by Richard Hein worked for me. I was compiling with VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in Visual Studio C++ 2010. I did not installed any Service packs or updates of VS and this problem arises when I had two rc files which tried to use ICONs. So I just taken content of one file and cut it into the main file. So only one file contains the ICONS and the second file is empty. Works like sharm :-).

Answer (score 0):

Replace else block in Dmitry Markin answer to recursively update all project files

```
else: # recursively update all project files in current directory:
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):        
        for filename in files:
            if(filename.endswith('.vcxproj')):
                filePath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                print "file: %s" % (filePath)
                updateProject(filePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer for this error. I am sorry to burst the bubble. None of the answers worked out for me.
My mistake was I had defined 3 MACRO's with same id. That is the reason I was getting the error mentioned in the question.

my code before when the error was showing:

```
#define IDB_MARKER_NORMAL_LINE          21**6**   
#define IDB_MARKER_ARROW_LINE           21**6**   
#define IDB_MARKER_DOTTED_LINE          21**6**
```

i changed it to:

```
#define IDB_MARKER_NORMAL_LINE          21**6**   
#define IDB_MARKER_ARROW_LINE           21**7**   
#define IDB_MARKER_DOTTED_LINE          21**8**
```

Errors were GONE!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this and I did the following in resource.h

```
#undef VS_VERSION_INFO
#define VS_VERSION_INFO                 310
```

As VS_VERSION_INFO is given resource id 1 in WinRes.h just making it something else fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> If you ever encounter this error while compiling (usually a downloaded project from internet), then remove the manifest file and
>   remove the reference to the manifest file in the .rc file.
>
> This answer by hB0 was 100% correct for the case I encountered.
>
> This was very useful to me and I would like others to benefit from
>   knowing this, rather than assuming hB0's answer should be ignored
>   because others have votes and hB0's has zero votes. I have to say it
>   in a separate answer because I the system will not let an unregistered
>   user vote. I even registered so as to be able to vote on this answer
>   but the system still will not let me vote till I am a more mature
>   user.

This answer point a way to find the problem that I encounted. In my senario, the import props has this code:

```
<ResourceCompile Include="$(VersioningDir)**Version.rc" />
```

When I delete it, all work is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever encounters CVT1100 (duplicate resource) & LNK1123 (failure during conversion to COFF) resource errors in Visual Studio 20XX, then do below steps to resolve it.

1. Open .rc file & comment / remove below MACRO

   MOVEABLE PURE   "res\.manifest"

2  Rename / Delete Manifest file from Resource folder from Project directory.

Now Re-build the solution & Enjoy...