# fatal error CVT1100: ressource en double. Type: VERSION, nom: 1, langage: 0x040C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, rc

This morning I have the following error when I attempt to compile my dll with cmake and nmake (Sorry for text in French):

```
 Création de la bibliothÞque core.lib et de l'objet core.exp
CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: ressource en double. Type: VERSION, nom: 1, langage: 0x040C
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: échec lors de la conversion en fichier COFF: fichier non valide ou endommagÚ
LINK Pass 1 failed. with 1123
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : code retour '0xffffffff'
```

Before, everithing works fine.

I use the script of https://github.com/halex2005/CMakeHelpers to make my versionning of file with cmake. Here is what I insert into my CMakeLists.txt :

```
[...]
file(GLOB SRC_FILES
    ${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
    ${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src/*.h
    )
[...]
if(MSVC)
    include(${MAIN_DIR}/platform/cmake/common/generate_product_version.cmake)
    generate_product_version(
    VersionFilesOutputVariable
    NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
    VERSION_MAJOR 0
    VERSION_MINOR 0
    VERSION_PATCH 0
    VERSION_REVISION 1
    COMPANY_NAME "COMPANY"
    FILE_DESCRIPTION "Librairie ${PROJECT_NAME}.dll"
    )
endif(MSVC)

[...]
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
    ${SRC_FILES}
    ${VersionFilesOutputVariable}
)
```

I have a folder `/platform/cmake/common/` with **VersionResource.rc**, **VersionInfo.in** and **generate_product_version.cmake** inside. These are the same files as the repos above.

I've read on many post ([fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource. type:ICON, name:1 (C++, Visual Studio C++ 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323596/) and [How to resolve CVT1100 in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403384/)) that it can come from duplicate file.rc or same variable (here VERSION apparently) who's call several times.

I've also test to put `/INCREMENT:NO` or `/MANIFEST:NO` as I see in other post on web.

After I search for any variable strictly called `VERSION` or something like that to change but anyway... I 'm not very comfortable with the rc files.

How I can resolve this issue please ?

And why suddenly it doesn't works ?

I use cmake 3.5.2 and Visual Studio 2015. I try to compile in Debug and x64.

Thanks for any help.